# Создание объекта класса, унаследованного от абстрактного

Tags: ооп, классы, c++

Здравствуйте.

В общем - есть 3 класса, один абстрактный, другие - производные.
В абстрактном описана виртуальная функция без реализации, а в двух других реализована.
Каким образом вызвать в main() реализованную функцию от каждого производного класса?

Вот код:

```
class components
{
    public:
        virtual int solve(void) = 0;
};

class componentsOne : public components
{
    public:
        int result, x, y;

        componentsOne(int x, int y) {
            printf("Create object First");
            printf("%d",solve(x, y));
        }

        int solve(int x, int y) {
            return result = x+y;
        }
};

class componentsTwo : public components
{
    public:
        int result, x, y;

        componentsTwo(int x, int y) {
            printf("Create object First");
            printf("%d",solve(x, y));
        }

        int solve(int x, int y) {
            return result = x*x+y;
        }
};
```

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class components
{
    public:
        virtual int solve() = 0;
};

class componentsOne : public components
{
    private:
        int m_x, m_y;
    public:

        componentsOne(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {
            std::cout << "Create object One\n";
        }

        int solve() {
            return (m_x+m_y);
        }
};

class componentsTwo : public components
{
    private:
        int m_x, m_y;
    public:

        componentsTwo(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {
            std::cout << "Create object Two\n";
        }

        int solve() {
            return (m_x*m_x+m_y);
        }
};

int main()
{
    components *object;

    object = new componentsOne(5, 2);
    std::cout << "ComponentOne->solve() === " << object->solve() << "\n";
    delete object;

    object = new componentsTwo(3, 2);
    std::cout << "ComponentTwo->solve() === " << object->solve() << "\n";
    delete object;

    return 0;
}
```

С помощью 1 указателя на базовый класс, можно работать со всем наследниками.

Comment: c:\projects\1l\15\15.cpp(57): error C2259: componentsOne: невозможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса
1>          из-за следующих членов:
1>          int components::solve(void): абстрактный
1>          c:\projects\1l\15\15.cpp(20): см. объявление "components::solve"
1>c:\projects\1l\15\15.cpp(61): error C2259: componentsTwo: невозможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса
1>          из-за следующих членов:
1>          int components::solve(void): абстрактный
1>          c:\projects\1l\15\15.cpp(20): см. объявление "components::solve"

Comment: И так не хочет, либо у меня что-то в коде не так... Либо с компилятором что-то не то.

Comment: Ну я не много переписал твой код. Так что пробуй. А лучше открой какую нибудь книжечку по С++.

Comment: У меня всё норм компилируется и запускается.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    componentsOne c1(2,4);
    int x1 = c1.solve();
    componentsTwo  c2(2,4);
    int x2 = c2.solve();
    return 0;
}
```

где то так.

**upd**

А определения классов нужно исправить так
    class components
    {
        public:
            virtual int solve() = 0;
    };

```
class componentsOne : public components
{
    public:
        int result, x, y;

        componentsOne(int x, int y) {
            printf("Create object First");
            printf("%d",solve());
        }

        int solve() {
            return x+y;
        }
};

class componentsTwo : public components
{
    public:
        int result, x, y;

        componentsTwo(int x, int y) {
            printf("Create object Two");
            printf("%d",solve()); // правда зачем оно здесь, да ещё в С стиле
        }

        int solve() {
            return x*x+y;
        }
};
```

Comment: Так не интересно. Интересно - с указателями на базовый и производный классы, в разных комбинациях

Comment: Это же очевидно, я бы не спрашивал. Это стандартное создание объектов. Тут же вроде что-то с указателями шаманить нужно :)

В общем, вот ошибки после вашего примера: error C2259: componentsOne: невозможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса
из-за следующих членов:
int components::solve(void): абстрактный
c:\projects\1l\15\15.cpp(20): см. объявление "components::solve"

Comment: Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @gecube, не то чтобы не интересно, мне бы и так сошло. Но оно же не компилится )

Comment: ну так, абстрактный метод то кривенький - сигнатуры разные.

Поэтому, либо в базовом написать ` virtual int solve(int x, int y) = 0;`

либо в наследниках писать правильно.

Я выбираю второй вариант.

Comment: Так у solve сигнатура разная. Поэтому и не компилит....

Answer (score -1):

В обоих ответах main - совершенно не интересны и, главное, не иллюстративны.

```
int main() 
{     
  components *Comp[2];
  Comp[0] = new componentsOne(3,5);
  Comp[1] = new componentsTwo(2,4);
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    Comp[i]->solve();//Вот, где самая сладость-то
  .................
  delete [] Comp;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: и в чем прикол в твоем коде?
ты используешь 2 указателя для двух объектов, а я у меня через 1 указатель работают с двумя объектами.
тогда уж делать такой пример.

    funct(components *comp)
    {
        comp->solve();
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        componentsOne compOne(3, 5);
        componentsTwo compTwo(2, 4);
    
        funct(&compOne);
        funct(&compTwo);
    
        return 0;
    }

Comment: а мы с Вами уже на "ты"? Я вижу, что Вы не поняли, и ничего удивительного в этом не нахожу.

Comment: @BuilderC, если честно, я тоже не вижу ничего принципиально отличного от варианта ТС.

Comment: К тому же, @BuilderC, у Вас ошибка. Смотрите, Вы создаете массив `Comp` на стеке, а потом применяете к нему `delete[]`. Наверное, Вы хотите освободить объекты в куче, на которые указывают члены этого массива? Так вот неправильно это делаете. Результат такого кода будет плачевен. Надо к каждому члену персонально применять `delete`

    delete Comp[0];
    delete Comp[1];

Comment: @mikillskegg, Вы совершенно правы в обоих своих комментариях. 1) полиморфизм показан более выпукло и 2) то-то у меня рука не поднималась этот delete писать.